# SQL Query with Parameters not working - ASP.NET with Oracle DB

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle11g

This works fine if I hard code the username. Will not work with parameters, I've tried lots of different ways. What am I missing? The table always ends up with zero count when I use the parameter.

```
    protected void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OracleConnection con = TTTrackerConnection.DevDBConnection();
    String myUserName = UserName.Text;
    DataSet user_ds = new DataSet();
    String myPW = Password.Text;
    using (con)
    {
        con.Open();

        String sql = "SELECT USER_PW FROM TT_USER WHERE USER_LOGINNAME = :username";
        OracleCommand cmdFindUser = new OracleCommand(sql, con);
        OracleParameter uname = cmdFindUser.CreateParameter();
        uname.ParameterName = "username";
        uname.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        uname.Value = UserName.Text;
        cmdFindUser.Parameters.Add(uname);
        OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmdFindUser);
        oda.Fill(user_ds);

        con.Close();
    }

    if (user_ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        String userPW = user_ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].Field<string>("USER_PW");
        if (myPW == userPW)
        {
            lblPasswordResult.Text = "Password Matched";

        }
        else
        {
            lblPasswordResult.Text = "Password does not Match";
        }
        }
    else
    {
        lblPasswordResult.Text = "Login not found";
    }
}//end Login button click method
```

Comment: Does `ParameterName` need to be prefixed with a `:`?

Comment: @DavidG I just tried that, it made no difference in result. Perplexing.

Comment: @DavidG only in the query. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleparameter.parametername(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: @LeeAmes syntax wise example code looks correct. could it be that the value of the parameter yields no results? a stray character? validate input before assigning it to parameter.

Comment: just looked up a bit of known-good code where we do the same thing. the only difference I found is an additional `uname.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;` but that is the default and should not make any difference. and we're always using the colon : before the name, also in the `ParameterName`. could it be a type mismatch - `OracleDbType.NVarchar2`?

Comment: @dlatikay Thank you! It was the type mismatch - I needed Char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Oracle parameter types used for strings, `OracleDbType.Varchar2` as well as `OracleDbType.NVarchar2`, you need to specify a size:

```
uname.Size = 50;
```

Where the actual value should correspond to the length in characters of the column according to schema (`USER_LOGINNAME` in your case).

Comment: The Size and the correct type (Char in this case) were the answers.  Thank you very very much!